# Refreshing data from api after stretching the viewcontroller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa, ipad

I have noticed that applications like facebook and washington post have certain viewcontrollers where if you stretch the viewcontroller below it says that the data is getting to reload. I sense it a better way of reloading the data rather than everytime its being called at viewWillAppear. I am just curious what is that functionality called, and is there any example for this online?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's usually called Pull to Refresh or Pull Down Refresh.

https://github.com/enormego/EGOTableViewPullRefresh